# Object Detection Flask App cuasing image overwrites in consecutive requests

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to implement an object detection web app using flask.

The flow of my app is:

- The user will upload an image.
- The image will get saved to a directory ('/static/uploads' folder)
- A function called '*get_images*' will read the image, load the object detector model, and finally write the image with detection at the specified folder ('/static/detections/')
- A template called '*uploaded.html*' will then display the uploaded image from the upload directory, and also the image with detections from detections directory.

**The app runs fine when ran for the first time and when the server is launched again. But if I try to upload another image after running detection on the first image, the image with detections get overwritten with the previous image but its name is preserved, ultimately resulting in the first image with detections being displayed again and again.** My flask app (app.py) code is as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/uploads/'
DETECTION_FOLDER = './static/detections/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER 
app.config['DETECTION_FOLDER'] = DETECTION_FOLDER
# app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0 
# app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
  return render_template("about.html")

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        # create a secure filename
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        print(filename)
        # save file to /static/uploads
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        print(filepath)
        f.save(filepath)
        print(filepath)     
        
        get_image(filepath,filename)
                
        return render_template("uploaded.html", display_detection = filename, fname = filename)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(port=4000, debug=True)
```

Function `get_image()` is a method of file  *`app_helper.py`* and is ultimately performing a *cv2.imwrite* on the image with detections. I thought the problem might be with this section of the code as this is the only place where any 'writing' is done. So, I ran the *app_helper.py* function multiple times, **and not once the images were overwritten** (in the '/static/detections/' folder).

I'm including some images to explain my concern better,

[Page after running the first detection looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL0kn.jpg)

['/static/detections/' folder after first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11ztm.png)

['/static/uploads/' folder after uploading my 2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAnfC.png)

[As soon I run the detector, this is what happens in the '/static/detections/' folder, though the file name is preserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Qxw.png)

And since the new file name (phone.jpg) is now associated with same image as 'phone2.jpg' the detection image doesn't not change. I kept repeating this, and any new image I uploaded - it got overwritten by 'phone2.jpg'!

I repeat, I tried running get_images() method separately - even after running it on multiple images NO SUCH OVERWRITES took place. For ref, get_images() method is a slight modification of [this](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/blob/master/detect.py) code. ('Uploaded.html' relies on the filename to display images, which is being maintained here)
e.g. `get_images('/data/images/kite.jpg','kite.jpg')`

ps- I also tried adding,

```
# app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0 
# app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

also, after the first execution, I emptied the *uploads* and *detections* folder to check if that helps,
But these didn't work.

Kindly help me out, I want my app to bear multiple runs (of upload and detect) without such issues.

Thank you.

Comment: isn;t in `get_image` part `filepath = os.path.dirname(filepath)` ? you have added file name and file path together earlier

Comment: @sahasrara62 I did, the reason why get_images is having 'filename' parameter despite having the entire path (with file name at the end) is so that I can easily extract the image name and save the final image with detections as the same name, in the detections directory.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Still, I logged the paths and ran get_images manually with the logged paths, it didn't cause such issue.